# Interacting with external DB via Django

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm working on a Django app that interacts with an existing database (think ERP/transaction type data) to perform analysis. There will be minimal/no updating of the existing database mainly reading data in. Its just a simple small setup so no replication etc. issues to think about re. updating.

The analysis would result in new records created within the Django Model.

Currently the existing DB runs on PostgreSQL.

I am aware of Alex Gaynor's GSOC multidb code which, from what I gather is ticket #1142 which has no patch yet to trunk.

So from what I gather there are three options I can see:

1) Point Django db to the same db as the ERP and let it create the tables it needs within it (all the ERP tables have a prefix so there would be no collision) however this strikes me as hackey and a recipe for disaster.

2) Create a new db for Django and automatically copy over the required tables. Better but I cant update, thought I can probably live with this.

3) Try out the multidb patch.

Are there other better ideas out there? I'm leaning towards at least trying out the multidb patch but I'm a little worried about stability and forwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

How about not using Django's ORM layer at all for that DB? It the interaction is minimal, you might do it faster by just using direct SQL with the appropriate postgresql-python library.